# Need help using System.Windows.Shell.JumpList.SetJumpList();

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, jump-list

I'm really new to this so this is probably a very simple thing to answer but anyhow...
I need to use the method in the title to set a new jumplist for my windows form app, but i don't know what parameters it takes and where to get them. I've read about the method in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.jumplist.setjumplist.aspx) but their example only worked for a WPF app.

It says it takes the parameters:

> ***application***
>   Type: System.Windows.Application
>   The application associated with the JumpList.
>   
>   ***value***
>   Type: System.Windows.Shell.JumpList
>   The JumpList to associate with the application.

What i need to know is: What is the first parameter? And how to i access it in a win form app?

(In a WPF i would usually just write `App.current`, but it doesn't work for form apps)

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (C#).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a comparable object in WinForms to the WPF [System.Windows.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx) object.  As you'll notice, the [System.Windows namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.aspx) is specific to WPF.

I have seen this [this Windows API CodePack project](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) referenced and it may be another place that you can find more information to continue your endeavors.